# Xamarin.forms : how to add a gradient color for tabbar

Tags: android, ios, xamarin.forms, uitabbar

in xamrin froms app, we have a tabbar, we need to add some gradient color for that tab bar in both iOS and android devices. how can we that ? [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make a image with gradient color by your designer;
2. The apply it to tabbar like:

   `UITabBar.Appearance.BackgroundImage = image;`

> Official documents:
>   https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/UIKit.UITabBar+UITabBarAppearance/

Comment: any suggestions for android ?

Comment: For Android, for example, the tabbar layout is in Ressources/layout/Toolbar.xml , use: android:background="@drawable/yourImage"

Comment: image is working for iOS, but having issues with size. if fount this one in iOS native UITabBar.appearance().contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit. but unable to find content mode in Xamarin froms app delegate . Any suggestions ?