# How to apply gradient color for tabbed page in xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, gradient, tabbedpage

I am working on xamarin. forms application, where I could able to apply the navigation bar in gradient colors but I am unable to apply those gradient colors for the tabbed page in Android and iOS platforms. Is there any way to apply gradient color for the tabbed page in xamarin.forms.

Comment: Do you mean want set color to Tab bar?You can post image to show which effect wanted.

Comment: Hope it helps. [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48092841/xamarin-forms-how-to-add-a-gradient-color-for-tabbar) let me know if any Query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not understand which effects you want.When have posted image,I will check this answer.

Maybe this is your want, do this in your Xamarin.Forms project like this.

```
var tabbedPage = new TabbedPage()
{
   BackgroundColor = Color.LightGray;
   BarBackgroundColor = Color.Black,
   BarTextColor = Color.White
};
```

Or set those properties in `.xaml`.

Comment: Thanks for the help.